# How to best handle year-only values in R

Tags: r, date

This is my first question on stackoverflow, and I'm a novice R programmer.
I have a dataframe where there is column "year" that has values from 1985 to 2012.  These are imported by default as a factor from my csv file (which might be my first problem).  I want to create a new vector "Modern" that has the value 1 for all rows where the date is larger than 2008.  Said another way, I want to indicate with a "1" all data from 2009-2012.

Here is my current solution:

```
yearnum<-as.Date(year,format="%Y")
Modern<-ifelse(yearnum>"2008-12-30",1,0)
```

It works, but I have some questions.
1.  I tried using the `as.numeric` function, but instead of giving me a value like 2006, it renumbered by years starting with 1.  Why is that?
2.  Because I ended up using the `as.Date` function, R defaulted the month and day to today's month and day.  Could I have avoided that by retaining just the year, or at least recording 1/1/yyyy?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `?read.table`, you can pass an argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` so that you don't get conversion to factors.

Using `as.numeric` on a factor class doesn't work, but you can do `as.numeric(as.character(as.factor("2006")))`, which gives you 2006.

For dates, one solution is replacing `2006` like `as.Date(paste0(2006, '-01-01'))`, which gives you `"2006-01-01"`